# I can't get Flutter notification icons working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having serious trouble trying to get notification icons in Flutter working using Firebase Messaging - all I get a round grey circle no matter what I try to do.

I have created a flutter notification icon using the Android Asset builder, which has placed an appropriate icon in each of the app/src/main/res/drawable-*dpi folders. I've tried copying it to the main drawable folder as well with no luck.

I've also added the following to app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml under the main activity (with the filename being notification_icon).

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

My flutter doctor is this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
```

Any ideas? I've even tried using the drawable as an android payload under Firebase but still not luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue before and I solve this issue by myself.

**You should add a transparent icon for this.**

If you don't add a transparent icon you will see a gray icon

Sample transperent image: https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/car-fire.png

Comment: It is a transparent icon unfortunately :(

I made it with the Android Icon designer, it's a white icon on a transparent background as a .png